Slow speed Ethernet issue on Ubuntu 24.04
I recently changed my system to Ubuntu from Windows and I use my mobile and USB ethernet to connect, I used to get 500+ mbps on Windows by using USB tethering, but on Ubuntu 24.04 I am getting only 4 mbps. I am new to Ubuntu please help me solve this.
sudo lshw -C network

output:
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 50:eb:f6:9a:97:00
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:85104000-85104fff memory:85100000-85103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:8
       logical name: enx7aabaf4fc17d
       serial: 7a:ab:af:4f:c1:7d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.215.97 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

and after this command
sudo lspci

output:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4630 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH Shared SRAM (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH HECI Controller #1 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 11)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a87 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH SPI Controller (rev 11)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: INNOGRIT Corporation NVMe SSD Controller IG5216 (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)


I do not have any answers, but am encountering this exact issue...  If I find anything else, I'll post again
